# Is there a chemical reaction without a chemical change?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Chemical transformation alters the chemical properties of a material, which includes reactivity with various chemical species.  The new specials thus formed have different characteristics from the initials.

The chemical reaction breaks bonds, forms bonds, or both.  Basically, the atoms within the species reorganize into a new combination, producing a new chemical species with different chemical properties.

Can a chemical reaction happen without a transformation?  There is a chemical balance that pH and chemical properties do not change ...

If there is a chemical reaction in which there is no transformation, what example can you give me?

Comment: $$\ce{OH- + H2O -> H2O + OH-}$$

Comment: Isomerization of ethylene

Comment: trombho, it will be just a waste of time to continue thinking about this "problem". It is a play of words. A chemical reaction at equilibrium appears to be static yet bonds are being broken and re-formed. What is a chemical change?

Comment: Sure, there are great many such reactions, the simplest probably being $\ce{H^. + H2 -> H2 + H^.}$. Not that they matter much, though.

Comment: The H+H2 (and D+H2 and H+D2) reaction has been extensively studied both theoretically and experimentally in low pressure vacuum using molecular beams. The rotational and vibrational energy in the products fits with quantum calculations. Search for 'reaction dynamics and 'reactive scattering'.

Comment: @porfirina Minimal changes, so whenever a chemical reaction occurs, a transformation will inevitably happen?  I am confused by this, because I had read books that these words are different from the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for describes the state of thermodynamic equilibrium. Many examples you've been presented are reactions of the form $$\ce{A^* +B<->B^* +A}$$ which do not "transform" the properties of the system as a whole. The reactions permute the arrangement of atoms into chemically identical arrangements. From a thermodynamic standpoint they are equivalent initial and final states.

If you look at a collection of molecules in aggregate you might identify other reactions called [isomerizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomerization), including [tautomerizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautomer), that involve rapid changes in the structure of a molecule between various structural forms. In a given sample you will encounter all such isomers in equilibrium concentrations, and if you focus on just one single molecule you will see it sample all of the possible isomers, provided you wait long enough. During that time, if the system is in equilibrium, the properties of the sample as a whole will not change and the relative proportions of the different isomers will be preserved.

Comment: A clear distinction can be observed with a hypothetical example of assuming a dynamic chemical equilibrium between 2 species A and B in a mixture. A converts into B and with same rate B converts into A. A→B and B→A occurs simultaneously. If rate of forward reaction is same as that of backward reaction, it is known as dynamic equilibrium. So 2 chemical reactions are taking place everytime but no visible change appears. No chemical change occurs in the mixture as the chemical properties such as pH of mixture experience no change but reaction is taking place everytime.

Comment: I think there may be a chemical reaction without a chemical change, I am still not convinced that it is not (at the same time I am confused)